# How to migrate XML type oracle data to Hadoop HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, xmltype

I have huge data in Oracle in one table and one column type is XML type which contains main data. I need to move this data to HDFS. What should be the best way to migrate this data in Hadoop HDFC. Any sample code or instructions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to move data as flat (or csv) files to HDFS or import table to one of HIVE DB. In case of HIVE Import, you can use Sqoop. Sqoop is used to import data from RDBMS Databases to HIVE DB.

Comment: Both, xml type from Oracle to HDFS.....can xml type directly be stored in HIVE, will sqoop support that.......I am fairly new to HADOOP world.

Comment: You can store xml data in a HIVE column and then use XPATH on top of it. Please see https://communities.intel.com/community/itpeernetwork/datastack/blog/2013/08/15/hadoop-tutorials-ingesting-xml-in-hive-using-xpath. One thing you need to be careful about is xml data should not have line breaks in between